# How to get the middle of a string in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Hold on: It's not as easy as it sounds in the title.

I've been working on a very crude AI, and the seemingly hard bits have been easy but this one little function is being really hard.

What I want this to do is get some of the chars that occur before a chars in the string. For example,

```
get_piece_behind("Hello World", 5, 3) #Return the 3 chars that come before ' ' (the fifth char)
'llo'
get_piece_behind("Hello World", 4, 3) #Return the 3 chars that come before 'o' in "hello" (the fourth char)
'ell'
get_piece_behind("Hello World", 5, 2) #Return the 2 chars that come before the fifth char
'lo'
```

The code accepts a string, an int marking a place in the string, and an int telling the function how far back it should look.

I get the idea this should be a super-simple one-liner... but my coffee infused brain has been staring at it for the past hour, rewriting it over and over, and nothing seems to work (my current function returns small bits of string, but from the wrong place)

```
def get_piece_behind(string, place, length_of_piece): #My current function
    string = string[(place - length_of_piece):] 
    string = string[:place] 
    return string
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I get the idea that it's a tiny, stupid error that I will have completely overlooked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it in one line :) since your string change after first reassignment, also character positions will change:

```py
def get_piece_behind(_string, place, length_of_piece): #My current function
    _string = _string[(place - length_of_piece):place] 
    return _string
```

Comment: Thanks! When working on it, I knew it could be done in one line, but I broke it in two because I was getting really confused and wanted to try doing things one at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Python strings are sequences, and as such you can use the slice-index syntax to retrieve sub-sequeces of it:

```
a = "hello world"
a[1:3]  # retrieves the chars from the second posistion (index 1) up to the 4th.
# the same, but as you want, putting expressins to calculate the indexes:
a[5-3:5]
a[4-3:4]
```

I suggest you to read the following document in whole before proceeding with your task - might save you a lot of time:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

You are overlooking in your string splicing.

Try this:

```
def get_piece_behind(string, place, length_of_piece):
    string = string[(place-length_of_piece) : place] 
    return string
```

Answer (score 0):

The index of characters changes as you cut first with `place - length_of_piece`, which gives `2`, so you were cutting *from* third char, `"llo World"` then 5 characters before, resulting in `"llo W"`.

**This should work for you:**

```py
def get_piece_behind(string, place, length_of_piece):
    return string[place-length_of_piece:place]
```

**Output:**

```py
llo
ell
lo
```